# DocuSign API: When populating template's PDF form fields by tag, why do Text tabs get duplicated in the upper-left corner of every document?

Tags: python, docusignapi

Our team has been using the Docusign Python API for about a year now and we've noticed this issue pretty consistently, then disappear for a few weeks, and now it's back again. Every time we generate a new template with Text tabs anchored somewhere on the document, the Tabs get duplicated into the upper-left corner of the document. The resulting document has a bunch of overlapping text fields in the corner of the first page, which looks very unprofessional and messy.

Here's what the template looks like. The two fields stacked on top of each other are hard to see since they've been shrunk down to the minimum size, but if I click on them I can see that their tab labels match the two fields on the page (broker_name and sign_date).

[image: Template preview with empty fields.]

Then during the signing ceremony for an envelope built from this template, the empty fields get populated with data, and show up in the corner.

[image: Envelope with duplicated tabs.]

We generate the Tabs object with the following code:

```
# Returns a Tabs object with name and date tabs. For envelopes that only contain those two fields.
def generate_name_date_tabs(name, date):
    name = Text(document_id = '1', page_number = '1', recipient_id = '1', value=name, tab_label = 'eh_broker_name')
    date = Text(document_id = '1', page_number = '1', recipient_id = '1', value=date, tab_label = 'eh_sign_date')

    return Tabs(text_tabs=[name, date])
```

And we generate the template and envelope here:

```
def create_application_envelope(destination_email, base64_file_content, signer_name="PlanProvide", signer_tabs=None, is_embedded_signing=False):
    # Create an application envelope
    # docusign_auth.DSClient.login("jwt")
    account_id = session["ds_account_id"]
    envelope_api = docusign_api_handler.get_envelope_api()
    templates_api = docusign_api_handler.get_templates_api()

    access_code = generate_access_code()
    
    signer = Signer(
        email=destination_email,
        name=signer_name,
        recipient_id="1",
        routing_order="1",
        role_name="signer",
        # Use a six-character access code so URL doesn't expire
        access_code=access_code,
        tabs=signer_tabs
    )

    doc = Document(
        document_base64 = base64_file_content,
        name = "Your application generated by PlanProvide",
        file_extension = "pdf",
        document_id = 1,
        # Detect Adobe form field names
        transform_pdf_fields = True
    )
    documents = [doc]
    template_req_object = EnvelopeTemplate(
        documents=documents, email_subject="Please sign this document",
        recipients=Recipients(signers=[signer]),
        description="Template created via the API",
        name="Application Template",
        shared="false",
        status="created"
    )
    try:
        res = templates_api.create_template(account_id=account_id, envelope_template=template_req_object)
    except Exception as e:
        raise DocusignError(e)

    try:
        template_id = res.templates[0].template_id
    except:
        template_id = res.template_id
    envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
        email_subject="Please sign this document sent from the Python SDK",
        template_id=template_id,
        template_roles=[signer],
        status="sent"  # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
    )
    # Send it to an email
    try:
        results = envelope_api.create_envelope(account_id=account_id, envelope_definition=envelope_definition)
    except Exception as e:
        raise DocusignError(e)

    return {
        "envelope_id": results.envelope_id,
        "access_code": access_code
    }
```

As far as I can tell, the Tabs object still has only the two Text fields all the way up to the template creation, so I'm not sure why the duplicates appear. Any help or ideas with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Here's where we call generate_name_date_tabs():

```
tabs = docusign_api_handler.generate_name_date_tabs(name, datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%y'))

    try:
        resp = application_services.create_application_envelope(
            destination_email,
            base64_file_content,
            signer_name=name,
            signer_tabs=tabs, is_embedded_signing=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the problem.

You're defining the tabs inside `signer` by providing the `tabs` field. Later down the code, when you're creating the envelope, you again provide the same `signer` in `templateRoles`:

```
  except:
        template_id = res.template_id
    envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
        email_subject="Please sign this document sent from the Python SDK",
        template_id=template_id,
        template_roles=[signer],
        status="sent"
```

I'd change `template_roles=[signer]` to `templateRoles=[{"email":"email@domain.com", "name": "name", "roleName" : "signer"}]` and update

```
signer = Signer(
        recipient_id="1",
        routing_order="1",
        role_name="signer",
        # Use a six-character access code so URL doesn't expire
        access_code=access_code,
        tabs=signer_tabs
    )
```

to not include name and email.

If that doesn't work, we'd need to dig in some more.Can you please show where you call `generate_name_date_tabs`?

Also can you show what's assigned to `signer_tabs` in the code below?

```
signer = Signer(
        email=destination_email,
        name=signer_name,
        recipient_id="1",
        routing_order="1",
        role_name="signer",
        # Use a six-character access code so URL doesn't expire
        access_code=access_code,
        **tabs=signer_tabs**
    )
```

If you're seeing the issue disappearing and appearing with different releases, I might very well be a bug. Let us know if any of above is useful in narrowing down the problem.

Comment: I've edited my post to include the call to generate_name_date_tabs. I tried changing the template_roles and signer, and although this did remove the duplicate fields, it also made it so the name and date tabs didn't populate with the values I passed in. If there's a way to populate PDF form fields with default values _without_ creating a template first that might fix it, but I couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: Actually, I tried your fix on the signer in the `template_req_object` and it worked! I changed the recipients to `recipients=Recipients(signers=[{"email":destination_email, "name": signer_name, "roleName" : "signer", "recipientId": "1", "routingOrder": "1"}])` and it removed the duplicate tabs, but still populated the envelope tabs.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you want a date/time when it's signed, don't use a **textTab**, but a **dateSignedTab**. That one automatically fill in the date/time when the document is signed.

Second, you are using a template. If your template has tabs define - they would be there in addition to the tabs in your code.

Third, if you don't provide location (X/Y coordinates) and no **anchorText**, the tab would be placed in position 0/0 or upper left corner like you see.

So, the one in the right place is probably coming from the template, the one in your code is showing in the upper left corner cause no position was specified.

Comment: Rather than using X/Y coordinates or anchorText (anchor_string in Python), we're using tab_label to match the locations of existing PDF form fields, and populating those fields with data. I do think the issue has something to do with creating tabs for the template, and then also assigning them to the envelope, but that was the only way I could get the fields to populate with our data.

Comment: remove the tabs from your code and see what happens